# How do I get rid of this toolbar in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How do I get rid of this toolbar shown in the picture? I fatfingered some keys and now I can't get rid of it, primarily because I'm not 100% sure what it is...

[image: Strange Toolbar]

This is in the normal Java perspective. I've tried resetting the perspective, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the breadcrumb bar. It shows the details of the location of the class you're currently editing. It's useful to quickly see if you're editing the correct class, and you can use it to navigate to other locations in your project as well.

If you want to turn it off click this button in the toolbar: [image: breadcrumb button]

Answer (score 3):

The annoying toolbar you're describing is called the Java Editor Breadcrumb (see [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm))

It can be disabled by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> and toggling Java Editor Breadcrumb